# woocommerce-api not populating variable to display data in ionic

Tags: ionic3, woocommerce-rest-api

im using woocommmerce-api and ionic to pull data from woocommerce site but it does not showing data on front end, i can see data in console.
when try to assign it to variable it returns null/undefined.
Can somebody help/suggest solution. snippet of code is below.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController,ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';
import * as WC from 'woocommerce-api';
import { WoocommerceProvider } from '../../providers/woocommerce/woocommerce';
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  WooCommerce: any;
  products: any[];
  moreProducts: any[];
  page: number;
  searchQuery: string = "";

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,private WP: WoocommerceProvider, public toastCtrl: ToastController) {
    this.page = 2;

    this.WooCommerce = WP.init();
    this.products=[]
    this.WooCommerce.getAsync("products").then( (data) => {
      console.log(data.toJSON().body); --> this shows data in console.
      this.products = data.toJSON().body;
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err)
    })

    console.log(this.products); --> in console this is empty/undefined

  }
```

Comment: found solution, if it helps anybody for future ref, here is the solution:- 

using async/await till promise settles

 'async get_product(){
    await this.WooCommerce.getAsync("orders").then( (data) => {
      // console.log(JSON.parse(data.body));
       this.products = JSON.parse(data.body);
       //console.log(this.products);
     });
  }'